Blazor .NET 8 : subscribe to async event
I'm trying to get my child components to subscribe to a notification event by invoking it inside my service. How do I subscribe to it? I'm getting an error stating I cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>.
Here's my service implementation:
public event Func<Task> Notify;

Then I have a child method to call inside my service:
public async Task Subscribe(string value)
{
    ...
    await Notify!.Invoke();
}

Then in my child component, I'm trying to subscribe like so:
private async Task OnNotify()
{
    await InvokeAsync(() =>{
        ...
        StateHasChanged();
    });        
}

Inside my OnInitializedAsync() method is where I'm trying to subscribe but I get the above error:
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Notifier.Notify += OnNotify();
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

How do I subscribe to an asynchronous event when it returns Func<Task>?

"but I get the above error:" which error?

cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>

are you getting the error on this line? Notifier.Notify += OnNotify();

Notifier.Notify += OnNotify; or Notifier.Notify += () => OnNotify();

Thanks @StriplingWarrior. I knew I was doing something stupid!
